# pyqt5 write right to left qlineedit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlineedit

How to achieve writing from right to left in qlineedit? I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

```
self.input_field = QLineEdit()
self.input_field.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)  # this is what you need!
```

**Full code:**

```
# import libraries you need!
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # some code

        self.input_field = QLineEdit()
        self.input_field.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)  # this is what you need!

        # some code

        container = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(container)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```